# Error SML: unbound variable or constructor

Tags: sml

I am new to SML. I tried to create and test the following function below, but I received an error. I do not know what is the problem.

```
fun isOld(pFirstTuple: int*int*int, pSecondTuple: int*int*int) = 
    if (#1 pFirstTuple) < (#1 pSecondTuple)
    then 
        true
    if (#1 pFirstTuple) = (#1 pSecondTuple)
    then 
        if (#2 pFirstTuple) < (#2 pSecondTuple)
        then
            true

    else
        false
```

I have tried this command "val p = isOld((8,9,10),(10,11,12))", but it showed me the following error **Unbound variable or constructor**. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what your code looks like, stripped down by ignoring various subexpressions (replacing them with `A`, `B`, and `C`)

```
if A
then true
if B
then if C
     then true
else false
```

You're making extensive use of `if`/`then`/`else`, but the syntax is not quite correct. In SML, every `if` *must* have both a `then` *and* `else` clause associated with it. Here's my guess at what you actually meant:

```
if A
then true
else if B
then if C
     then true
     else false
else false
```

This is starting to get quite messy---but you can clean it up with boolean logic. Notice, for example, that `if X then true else false` means exactly the same thing as simply writing `X`, because both expressions are type `bool` and will always evaluate to the same boolean, regardless of what `X` is. You can extend this reasoning to see that

1. `if X then true else Y` is equivalent to `X orelse Y`.
2. `if X then Y else false` is equivalent to `X andalso Y`.

With these ideas, we can clean up your code considerably:

```
A orelse (B andalso C)
```